# Android RelativeLayout alignParentRight does not properly align Imageview

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, alignment

I am trying to place my ImageView in the bottom right corner of my display. I would like for the image to expand dynamically for different size displays.

The image aligns properly when it is smaller and not set to expand, but when set it to fill_parent the image is moved to the left and no longer lines up flush with the right side of the display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/surface1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></SurfaceView>
    <ImageView 
        android:src="@+drawable/image_1_patched" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        ></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make the image take up as much room as possible and remain flush to the right side of the display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the scaletype of your imageview to FIT_XY.

Comment: I tired fitCenter, but as you might expect that left the image in the center.  However fitEnd aligned the image flush to the right and bottom.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No worries. I copied the wrong tag. There are multiple options based on how you want it to scale. fitXY if you don't care about aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not solve the problem, but if you are wanting the image to stay on the bottom, you may want to add this to your imageview `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`